# Python - pass a method to every method I call

Tags: python

I have unstructured data that comes from two sources, and I have two different methods to parse that into a dictionary format depending on the source (device_type). From this dictionary, I then can call other methods based on the data. Here is what I have now:

```
Class ParseData:

   def __init__(self, device_type, data):    
       if device_type == 'a':
           self.create_dict_a(data)
       elif device_type == 'b':
           self.create_dict_b(data)

   def create_dict_a(self):
       return self.dict

   def create_dict_b(self):
       return self.dict

   def do_action_a(self):
       return actions

   def do_action_b(self):
       return actions

   def do_action_c(self):
       return actions

   def do_action_d(self):
       return actions

device_type = 'a'
x = ParseData(device_type, data_1).do_action_a()
x = ParseData(device_type, data_2).do_action_b()

device_type = 'b'
y = ParseData(device_type, data_3).do_action_c()
y = ParseData(device_type, data_4).do_action_d()
```

What I want to do is call it like this (since the device_type stays the same with multiple data inputs):

```
x = ParseData(device_type_a)
x1 = x.do_action_a(data_1)
x2 = x.do_action_b(data_2)

y = ParseData(device_type_b)
y1 = y.do_action_c(data_3)
y2 = y.do_action_d(data_4)
```

and have the `create_dict_a` or `create_dict_b` method be passed to the data input based on the device_type before the called 'action' method is run. Is there a way to do this, or a better way to go about this? I know I can just call the `create_dict` method in each action method, but I have a lot of methods and that just seems ugly.

Comment: create_dict_a and create_dict_b returns a dictionary, do u want that to be passed as an argument to your do_action_x functions? or you want the create_dict_a and create_dict_b to store the value in self object and the do_action_x refers form that ?

Comment: I want to pass it like `x1 = x.do_action_a(data_1)`, with `data_1` being the unstructured data, so that the `create_dict` method is passed to `data_1` before the action method is. If that makes sense.

Comment: and in turn to the do_action, u want to pass x1?

Comment: Yes. Essentially, `data_1` is an lxml structure. `create_dict_a` converts that to a dict, then `do_action_a` returns interesting items from the created dict (in dict format). I have a bunch of data and each one has a corresponding `do_action` method to retrieve the interesting data, and each data set would need to be converted to a dictionary first by `create_dict_a` or `create_dict_b` (which is just simply xmltodict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to explore decorators to solve this problem..

a rough solution would look something like this:

```
def create_dict_a(data):
    '''your logic here'''
    print("I am in create_dict_a..")
    return {}

def create_dict_b(data):
    '''your logic here'''
    print("I am in create_dict_b..")
    return {}

def curate_data(func):
    def wrapper(self, data):
        mydict = {}
        if self.deviceType == 'a':
            mydict =  create_dict_a(data)
        else:
            mydict =  create_dict_b(data)
        return func(self, mydict)
    return wrapper

class ParseData:
    def __init__(self, deviceType):
        self.deviceType = deviceType
    @curate_data
    def do_action_a(self, mydict):
        print("in do_action_a")
        return
    @curate_data
    def do_action_b(self, mydict):
        print("in do_action_b")
        return
 o = ParseData('a')


o.do_action_a(data={})

o_b = ParseData('b')

o_b.do_action_a(data={})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear why you want to do this, but I think what you're after here is a case where subclasses may help.

Look at this example:

```
class Parser:
    @classmethod
    def from_device_type(cls, device_type: str):
        if device_type == 'a':
            return ParserA()
        elif device_type == 'b':
            return ParserB()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown device type')

    def __init__(self):
        self.content = {}


class ParserA(Parser):
    def action_1(self):
        self.content[1] = 'A'


class ParserB(Parser):
    def action_1(self):
        self.content[1] = 'B'


pa = Parser.from_device_type('a')
pa.action_1()
print(pa.content)

pb = Parser.from_device_type('b')
pb.action_1()
print(pb.content)
```

```
{1: 'A'}
{1: 'B'}
```

There's one class that implements all the behaviour you need for either device type, `Parser`.

Then there's two classes that inherit from it `ParserA` and `ParserB`, that inherit all that behaviour, but add behaviour that may be specific for some device type.

Additional, I've added a class method to `Parser` that returns an instance of either `ParserA` or `ParserB`, depending on a device type.

I don't think that last bit is necessarily the best way to do things, but without a better understanding of the problem you're actually trying to solve, it's hard to see what the best solution here is - I figured knowing about these possibilities might just answer your question.

Edit: I just realised it may not be be obvious from the example, but `pa` is an instance of `ParserA` and `pb` is an instance of `ParserB` (and both are of course also instances of `Parser`).

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, type):
    self.type = type

  def create_dict(self, data):
    if self.type == 'a':
      return {'a' : data}
    else:
      return {'b' : data}

  def do_action(self, data):
    data = self.create_dict(data)
    print('nice'+ ' ' + self.type+ ' ' +data[self.type])

a = A('a')
a.do_action('1')
a.do_action('2')
a.do_action('3')
b = A('b')
b.do_action('4')
b.do_action('5')
b.do_action('6')
```

in this case we call the create dict directly into the do action which would make the code more cleaner
The output would be:

```
nice a 1
nice a 2
nice a 3
nice b 4
nice b 5
nice b 6
```